# Delete python variables per type

Tags: python, variables, types

I would like to ask if Python has some command to delete all variables of a predefined type. For example the command **del** needs the variable name specified, while I would like to do something like **del all float variables**.

Otherwise I would like to write a function, here sketched in a sort of pseudocode

```
def clear_variables():
    for variable in list_variables():
        if type(variable) == float:
           del variable
return
```

Any suggestions?

Many thanks!

Comment: FWIW, if you think you need something like this, your code could probably use a lot of improvement. You hardly ever need to delete variables if you use relatively short functions and store various data of the same type in containers like lists or dicts…

Comment: Your function wouldn't work either. Assigning an object to a new name (like `variable`) increases its reference count. `del variable` simply deletes that *name*, returning the reference count to where it was before the assignment. Understand what `del` actually does, then think about what it is that you actually want to accomplish. `del` really isn't used that often.

Comment: There's almost certainly no good reason to do this

Answer (score 1):

Lets hope your list_variables is an actual list, if not, you should assign it to a list first so you can properly deal with it.

```
def clear_variables():
    for index, variable in enumerate(list_variables):
        if type(variable) == float:
            list_variables.pop(index)

return
```

But you really should use `isinstance` instead:

```
def clear_variables():
    for index, variable in enumerate(list_variables):
        if isinstance(variable, (float,))
            list_variables.pop(index)

return
```

Or in one line:

```
list_variables = [variable for variable in list_variables if not isinstance(variable, (float,))]
```